# Deployment of CosmosDB with shared autoscaling throughput fails

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

Trying to deploy ARM Template for a Database Account, SQL Database with two Collections where autoscale throughput setting are set at the database level (shared for collections).

I created this setup in Azure UI and then exported the template.
When importing the template from Powershell using `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` it fails with message

```
Status Message: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.
ActivityId: <redacted>, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0 (Code:NotFound)
```

This is ridiculous because I exported the template and did not modify it and then imported. Isn't Azure recognizing it's own format?
I think the problem has to do with this fragment of template:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/throughputSettings",
    "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('databaseAccounts_an_test_name'), '/', parameters('databaseAccounts_an_test_name'), '-db-2/default')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases', parameters('databaseAccounts_an_test_name'), concat(parameters('databaseAccounts_an_test_name'), '-db-2'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('databaseAccounts_an_test_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "resource": {
            "throughput": 400,
            "autoscaleSettings": {
                "maxThroughput": 4000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy a new database and containers or update an existing one?

Comment: @MarkBrown create or update if possible

Comment: Yes, then use the example below with throughput getting set in the options. Works on create and can be redeployed to update RU/s too.  --thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Mark Brown hints this is the exact solution.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases",
    "name": ...
    "apiVersion": "2020-04-01"
    "dependsOn": ...
    "properties": {
      "resource": {
        "id": ...
      },
      "options": {
        "autoscaleSettings": {
          "maxThroughput": 4000
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Don't use the `Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/throughputSettings` part of yaml from exported template. I'm not sure why Azure exports it and then doesn't allow for import.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a new database or container resource you need to pass the throughput in the options for the resource. You can only use the throughput resource directly when updating the throughput.

Here is an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-sql-with-resource-manager#create-autoscale)